# Partition function and Fibonacci n-th number upperbound

Tags: fibonacci-numbers, integer-partitions

i need to proof this upperbound:

"Call $p(n)$ the number of partitions of n (integer) and $F_n$ the $n-th$ Fibonacci number. Show that
$p(n)\leq p(n-1) + p(n-2)$ and that $p(n)\leq F_n$ for $n\geq 2$"

Now i searched a little bit on through questions here and i found this
[The number of partitions of $n$ and the $n$th Fibonacci number.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/865452/the-number-of-partitions-of-n-and-the-nth-fibonacci-number)
where the second bound is prooved asimptotically but this is not my case. Plus passing from the first inequality i have to the second one is just a matter of saying that the sum of the two $p(n-1)+p(n-2)$ is just the $n-th$ Fibonacci number or i need to say something more ? (i think yes). Anyway my idea was to use the famous relation
$p(n)=p(n-1)+p(n-2)-p(n-5)-p(n-7)+p(n-12)+p(n-15)...$ and so on but i can't get it straight forward from this. Any hint?

Answer (score 2):

**Notations**: $F_0=0, \space F_1=1, \space F_{n+1}=F_{n}+F_{n-1}$. $p(n|"condition")=|\begin{Bmatrix} partitions \space of \space n \space verifying \space "condition" \end{Bmatrix}|$.

At first I think that you second inequality is false because $p(2)=2$ and $F_2=1$, so I will consider that the second inequality is $p(n) \le F_{n+1}$ for $n\geq1$.

We can notice that if the first inequality is true then the second is also true. Indeed by induction :
$$p(1)=1 \le 1=F_2$$
Suppose that the property is true for a certain $n\geq1$, let's show that it is also true for $n+1$:
$$p(n) \le p(n-1)+p(n-2) \le F_{n-1}+F_n=F_{n+1}$$
So by induction,  $\bbox[5px,border:2px solid green]{p(n) \le F_{n+1}}$ for $n\geq1$.

Let's prove the first inequality. $$p(n)=p(n|with \space a \space part \space 1)+p(n|without \space a \space part \space 1)=p(n-1)+p(n|without \space a \space part \space 1)$$
$$p(n-2)=p(n|with \space a \space part \space 2)$$
So we need to prove that :
$$p(n|without \space a \space part \space 1) \le p(n|with \space a \space part \space 2)$$
We consider a partition of $n$ without a part 1:
$$\lambda_1+\lambda_2+...+\lambda_k,\space \forall i, \space \lambda_i \geq 2 , \space \lambda_k \space being \space the \space smallest \space part$$
We can transform it into a unique partition with at least 1 part 2 by cutting the smallest part (which is $\geq 2$) into one 2-part and 0 or more 1-part. Thus we obtain :
$$\lambda_1+\lambda_2+...+\lambda_{k-1}+2+1+...+1 \space or \space \lambda_1+\lambda_2+...+\lambda_{k-1}+2$$
Then we merge all 1-parts and 1 2-part in order to have a partition with no 1-part. So we have :
$$p(n-2)=p(n|without \space a \space part \space 1)+p(n|smallest \space non \space 1part \space is < 2+number\space of \space 1part)$$
The last term is always non-negative, so : $$p(n|without \space a \space part \space 1) \le p(n|with \space a \space part \space 2)$$
Finally : $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid green]{p(n) \le p(n-1)+p(n-2)}$$

Comment: The function sending partitions without a $1$ part to partitions with a $2$ part doesn't seem to be injective.

$8+4+2$ and $8+6$ are mapped to the same partition (namely the first one) under the correspondence you describe.

Answer (score 0):

This answer uses Louis Kolitsch's short 2007 *Integers* [article](http://math.colgate.edu/%7Eintegers/cgi-bin/get.cgi) (freely available).

Write partitions in **non-decreasing** order.  We represent a partition $\lambda$ of $n$ as a tiling of a $1 \times n$ board by squares and dominoes ($1 \times 1$ and $1 \times 2$ pieces, respectively).  Turn each part 1 into a square and each larger part $\lambda_i$ into a domino followed by $\lambda_i - 2$ squares.

Here are the partitions of 5 and their corresponding tilings (using $\texttt{S}$ for a square and $\texttt{DD}$ for a domino).
\begin{array}{rcc}
5 & \sim & \texttt{DDSSS} \\
23 & \sim & \texttt{DDDDS} \\
14 & \sim & \texttt{SDDSS} \\
122 & \sim & \texttt{SDDDD} \\
113 & \sim & \texttt{SSDDS} \\
1112 & \sim & \texttt{SSSDD} \\
11111 & \sim & \texttt{SSSSS} 
\end{array}

It's been known since ancient India that tilings by squares and dominos are counted by the Fibonacci numbers (in the context of short and long vowels filling a metric line of poetry).  These tilings are the basis for Benjamin and Quinn's wonderful book *Proofs That Really Count* (MAA, 2003).  Since not all tilings correspond to partitions ($\texttt{DDSDD} \sim 32$ is the smallest example), this shows $p(n) \le f(n+1)$.

To directly prove the inequality $p(n) \le p(n+1) + p(n+2)$, we try to build tiling representations for $p(n)$ from those for $p(n-1)$ and $p(n-2)$.  Given a tiling of a partition counted by $p(n-1)$, add an initial $\texttt{S}$, i.e., add a part 1 to the partition.  This can always be done.  Given a tiling of a partition counted by $p(n-2)$, add an initial $\texttt{DD}$, i.e., turn the initial $k$ parts 1 into a part $k+2$.  This works only if the next part is at least $k+2$, which is not always the case (see below for building $p(5)$ from $p(3) + p(4)$).  Therefore $p(n) \le p(n+1) + p(n+2)$.

\begin{array}{rccccll}
4 & \sim & \texttt{DDSS} & \mapsto & \texttt{SDDSS} & \sim & 14 \\
22 & \mapsto & \texttt{DDDD}& \mapsto & \texttt{SDDDD} & \sim & 122 \\
13 & \mapsto & \texttt{SDDS}& \mapsto & \texttt{SSDDS} & \sim & 113 \\
112 & \mapsto & \texttt{SSDD}& \mapsto & \texttt{SSSDD} & \sim & 1112 \\
1111 & \mapsto & \texttt{SSSS}& \mapsto & \texttt{SSSSS} & \sim & 11111 \\ \hline
3 & \mapsto & \texttt{DDS}& \mapsto & \texttt{DDDDS} & \sim & 23 \\
12 & \mapsto & \texttt{SDD}& \mapsto & \texttt{DDSDD} & \sim & 32 & \text{X} \\
111 & \mapsto & \texttt{SSS}& \mapsto & \texttt{DDSSS} & \sim & 5
\end{array}

For more examples of when the transition from $p(n-2)$ to $p(n)$ doesn't work, here are the $p(5)$ partitions going in to $p(7)$.

\begin{array}{rccccll}
5 & \sim & \texttt{DDSSS} & \mapsto & \texttt{DDDDSSS}& \sim & 25\\
23 & \sim & \texttt{DDDDS} & \mapsto & \texttt{DDDDDDS}& \sim & 223\\
14 & \sim & \texttt{SDDSS} & \mapsto & \texttt{DDSDDSS}& \sim & 34\\
122 & \sim & \texttt{SDDDD} & \mapsto & \texttt{DDSDDDD}& \sim & 322 & \text{X} \\
113 & \sim & \texttt{SSDDS} & \mapsto & \texttt{DDSSDDS}& \sim & 43 & \text{X} \\
1112 & \sim & \texttt{SSSDD} & \mapsto & \texttt{DDSSSDD}& \sim & 52 & \text{X} \\
11111 & \sim & \texttt{SSSSS} & \mapsto & \texttt{DDSSSSS}& \sim & 7\\ 
\end{array}

So $p(7) = 15 = 11 + 4 = p(6) + 4$.