# Partitions of $n$ vs $(n-k_0)! $

Tags: integer-partitions

Let $p(n)$ denote the partitions of $n$. It's easy to prove that $p(n) < n!$ (for n>2). I want to prove that if $n \ge 6$ then $(n-2)! > p(n)$. Or more generally let $k_0\in \mathbb{N}$ be a fixed positive integer and suppose that for some $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$  $(n_0-k_0)! > p(n_0)$. Then $(n-k_0)! > p(n)$ for each $n \ge n_0$.

I don't know if this it's possible by simple methods because the recursive formulas for $p(n)$ are very complicated.

Comment: It seems that $2p(n)>p(n+1)$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$. If you prove it, your claim may follow by induction.

Comment: That would be very useful, because that implies even better inequalities. But I don't know how to prove it

Comment: It may help you: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1725833/partition-function-and-fibonacci-n-th-number-upperbound